# Munkres' Definition of Simply Connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Munkres defines simply connected as follows:

> A space $X$ is said to be simply connected if is a path-connected space and if $\pi(X,x_0)$ is the trivial (one-element) group for some $x_0 \in X$, and hence for every $x_0 \in X$.

I am not quite sure what is meant by the trivial group exactly. I know in a path-connected space it is possible to create loops since every two points are connected and if you start from $x_0$ you can get to $x_1$ and similarly you can go back from $x_1$ to $x_0$. What does it mean that it has to be trivial? It seems path connectedness does not necessarily imply simply connectedness. Could you please provide a example that a space is path connected but not simply connected?

Comment: Consider the circle.

Comment: For a group to be trivial means that it no elements other than its identity element.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial group is one which consists of only the identity element. $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is path connected but not simply connected.

Answer (score 1):

An element in the fundamental group is trivial if it is homotopic to the constant loop, that's null homotopic.

Look at a circle or torus ($S^1\times S^1$) for a path connected space that is not simply connected.

For intuition, it's pretty easy to see that any closed curve on a sphere can be shrunk, on the sphere, to a point, but not so on a circle or torus.